# Check existence of second tag with same name ensuring no error occurs if not present

Tags: vb.net

I have an XML with two tags of same name "column" as below:

```
<column>
   <entry>....</entry>
</column>   
<column>
   <entry>....</entry>
</column>
```

Now I need to assign first one to object named left and second to object named right.

There is no guarantee that either one or both of the column tags will be present. 
I am now calling xmlDocument.Root.Elements("column") to get both of the column elements and check if the count is more than 0 to get first one then check if count is more than 1 to get the second one.

```
If columns.count > 0 
  //get data from the first one
if columns.count > 1 
  //get data from second one.
```

However, I don't feel comfortable doing this. Is there a solution that handles all exceptions that might occur or a solution that ensures no error happens or just another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through all columns using for each. Demonstration:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim fileName As String = "yourXml.xml"
    Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load(fileName, LoadOptions.None)

    Dim columns As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = document.Root.Elements("column")

    For Each element As XElement In columns
        'get data
    Next
End Sub
```

Or if the index is important:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim fileName As String = "yourXml.xml"
    Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load(fileName, LoadOptions.None)

    Dim columns As XElement() = document.Root.Elements("column").ToArray()

    For index = 0 To columns.Length - 1
        Dim column As XElement = columns(index)
        'get data
    Next
End Sub
```